# MySQL: Match against dynamic values

Tags: mysql, select, string-matching, match-against

I have a list of values in a table column that I need to match against table names, preferably just using an SQL statement.

If the values were static, I suppose the SELECT statement would be something like this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE 
match(table_name) against('124512' +'36326' +'23636' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, I need to match against dynamic values coming from a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT tableid FROM databaseName.tableOverviewTableName 
WHERE template = 'templateName')
```

The *tableid* above is contained in the *table_name* for the tables that I want.

Is this possible to achieve with an SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Prepared statement (not directly via a query)

```
SET @tq = (SELECT tableid FROM databaseName.tableOverviewTableName WHERE template = 'templateName'));
SET @stmq = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @tq);
Prepare stmt FROM @stmq;
Execute stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but when I try to run the code above I get the error message "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row" on "SET @tq...". Besides, I need the selected number within the match-against expression.